# NGINX - proxying to a different Wordpress site while retaining URL

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I currently have two WORDPRESS websites sitting behind an NGINX proxy cache:

htxtp://local.example.com
htxtp://local.example.org

I want to access a URL from the first site but serve it from the second site whilst not losing the URL structure of the first (to allow website2.com to see the website1.com cookies).

For example:

I want:

htxtp://local.example.com/somepage/

To proxy the page built at:

htxtp://local.example.org/somepage/

BUT I don't want the URL to BE htxtp://local.website2.com.

My NGINX config is as follows:

```
server {
   listen      80;
   server_name local.example.com;
   access_log  logs/local.example.com.access.log;
   error_log   logs/local.example.com.error.log;


    location /somepage {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            local.example.org;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            local.example.com;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I am trying to work out where the actual redirect is happening.

Comment: Would be a nice question for http://serverfault.com/ And your links are not real anyway. For examples you should use the appropriate domains suggested by IANA: http://example.org or http://example.com

Comment: I've changed the example URLs